# Remove Single Quotes and Brackets from List

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

> I am new to Python and a bit puzzled. I want to remove single quote and a bracket from my output list. Below is my code:

```
with open('fft.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.rstrip(" \n ").split("=")
        if key in d:
             d[key].append(val)
        else:
             d[key] = [val]
    for x, v in d.items():
        print(x,set(v))
```

input from file:

```
t=w*A[7]
A[0]= u+t
A[1] = u+t
A[2] =u+t
A[3]= u+t
A[4] =u-t
t= w*A[7]
u= A[3]
w=w*w_8
```

the output from the above code

```
A[0]  {'u+t'}
A[1]  {'u+t'}
A[2]  {'u+t'}
A[3]  {'u+t'}
A[4]  {'u-t'}
t     {'w*A[7]'}
u     {'A[3]'}
w     {'w*w_8'}
```

expected output is:

```
A[0]  u+t
A[1]  u+t
A[2]  u+t
A[3]  u+t
A[4]  u-t
t     w*A[7]
u     A[3]
w     w*w_8
```

Comment: format code first

Comment: Input? Expected output? [mcve]?

Comment: No, put it in your question.

Comment: Is that 'expected input' exactly as your `fft.txt` file is? What is the expected output of your `print(newDict)`?

Comment: edit me question , add file input